Failed to use pinctrl/pinmux in port multiplexing
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and now I want to setup a UART port (with RXD/TXD/RTS/CTS) from 2 GPIO groups.
The DTS is setting as follows,
&pinctrl {
    uart0_pin: uart0-pin {
        uart0_test_porta: uart0-test-porta {
            rvsoc,pinmux = <&gpio_a 3 4>;
            rvsoc,pinmux-funcsel = <PINCTL_FUNC1>;
        };
        uart0_test_portc: uart0-test-portc {
            rvsoc,pinmux = <&gpio_c 0 1>;
            rvsoc,pinmux-funcsel = <PINCTL_FUNC1>;
        };
    };
};

&uart0 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart0_test_porta>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&uart0_test_portc>;
};

With above settings, I found only the PORTA is configured to work in UART mode, but PORTC is NOT being configured accordingly.
Is there anyting wrong in my DTS, and how can I make the combined PORTA and PORTC to work together as one 4-wire UART?
